# jQuery search on large HTML page

Tags: jquery, search

I have a task to complete for work. I have a HTML page with a table of products. I need to present a search box that allows the user to enter a product to search for, then use jQuery to search the page for words that match and then attach them in a div above the table as well as grabbing the href that they link to.

It's not possible to search the database as I don't have access to the server, has anyone done this before or seen any good resources or plugins. It seems a relatively easy task but I'm short on time.

Here's the following code I just put together, works great except I'm having trouble comparing against lowerCase / upperCase. Any ideas.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#searchButton').click(function() {
$(".searchresults").slideUp('fast', function(){

var arr = [];
var htmlsbr = "Your Search Results:<br />";

$('a:contains("' + $('#searchText').val() + '")').each(function() {
                                   arr.push($(this).text()+";"+$(this).attr('href'));
});

$.each(arr, function(index, value) { 
htmlsbr = htmlsbr + '<p><a href="'+value.split(';')[1]+'" name="'+value.split(';    ')[0]+'">'+value.split(';')[0]+'</a></p>';
});

$(".searchresults").append(htmlsbr).slideDown('slow');

}).html(' ');
});
});

</script>
<style>
p {color: brown;}
p.highlight {background-color: orange;}
body {background-color: beige;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="searchresults"></div>
<input id="searchText" value="second" />
<button id="searchButton">Search</button>
<p><a href="http://google.com" rel="this is the first entry.">This is the first entry.    </a></p>
<p><a href="http://ebay.com" rel="this is the second entry">This is the second entry.    </a></p>
<p><a href="http://msn.com" rel="this is the third entry.">This is the third entry.    </a></p>
<p><a href="http://yahoo.com" rel="this is the fourth entry.">This is the fourth entry.    </a></p>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery Replace Text plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-replacetext/docs/files/jquery-ba-replacetext-js.html)

Example (not tested) -

```
jQuery('selector').replaceText($("#yourtextbox").val(),function (str) {
    //do your stuff
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Quicksearch plugin](http://lomalogue.com/jquery/quicksearch/) could do the job.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'd rather use something lighter as it needs to work in IE6.